# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I am getting that exception from this code:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.materials = {}

    def add_material (self, m):
        self.materials[m.type + m.purity] = m

    def serialize (self):
        ser_str = 'transaction_start\n'

        for k, m in self.materials:
            ser_str += m.serialize ()

        sert += 'transaction_end\n'
        return ser_str
```

The `for` line is the one throwing the exception. The `m`s are `Material` objects. Anybody have any ideas why?

Comment: I had this issue when I expected a dictionary value to be a list of tuples. Instead it created a list of strings - with the Tuple syntax and I had to strip the surrounding brackets and split on the comma to break apart the tuple constituents.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`self.materials` is a [`dict`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and by default you are iterating over just the keys (which are strings).

Since `self.materials` has more than two keys[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053551/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack/7053615#comment34696354_7053615), they can't be unpacked into the [`tuple`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html#tuple) "`k, m`", hence the [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) [exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) is raised.

In Python 2.*x*, to iterate over the keys and the values (the [`tuple`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html#tuple) "`k, m`"), we use [`self.materials.iteritems()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).

However, since you're throwing the key away anyway, you may as well simply iterate over the dictionary's values:

```
for m in self.materials.itervalues():
```

In Python 3.*x*, prefer [`dict.values()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (which returns a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)):

```
for m in self.materials.values():
```

Comment: Something i didn't get here, why do you say it has more than 2 keys?

Comment: @NunoFurtado: 2.5 years later, I can only guess my younger self's reasoning. Here goes! Were there zero or one keys in `self.materials`, I'd expect the `ValueError` message to be `need more than n values to unpack`. Were there exactly two keys, these would have been unpacked into `k` and `m` (and presumably a different error would occur on the next line). Three or more keys? `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, per the title.

Comment: lol, hadn't even noticed the post age. i ran into a similar issue and i just don't get why that error would occur, none the less i used your solution to fix the problem

Answer (score 84):

```
for k, m in self.materials.items():
```

example:

```
miles_dict = {'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2.3, 'Wednesday':3.5, 'Thursday':0.9}
for k, v in miles_dict.items():
    print("%s: %s" % (k, v))
```

Answer (score 19):

Iterating over a dictionary object itself actually gives you an iterator over its *keys*. Python is trying to unpack keys, which you get from `m.type + m.purity` into `(m, k)`.

My crystal ball says `m.type` and `m.purity` are both strings, so your keys are also strings. Strings are iterable, so they can be unpacked; but iterating over the string gives you an iterator over its characters. So whenever `m.type + m.purity` is more than two characters long, you have too many values to unpack. (And whenever it's shorter, you have too few values to unpack.)

To fix this, you can iterate explicitly over the `items` of the dict, which are the (key, value) pairs that you seem to be expecting. But if you only want the values, then just use the values.

(In 2.x, `itervalues`, `iterkeys`, and `iteritems` are typically a better idea; the non-`iter` versions create a new list object containing the values/keys/items. For large dictionaries and trivial tasks within the iteration, this can be a lot slower than the `iter` versions which just set up an iterator.)

Comment: Thanks. Your tip helped me to solve my problem, when updating a dictionary of the form { 'longkey_n' : [ 'value_1', 'value_n' ] } :-D. My program also complained about too many values...