# ValueError too many values to unpack

Tags: python, powershell

My code:

```
from sys import argv
pl_magic, pl_pet = argv
pl_enemy = raw_input("The second enchanter:")
print "The most powerful enchanter is",pl_magic
print pl_pet,"is the pet of",pl_magic
print "They hate %s" %pl_enemy
```

Output in powershell:

```
PS D:\FILE\LPHW> python ex13b.py 1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex13b.py", line 2, in <module>
    pl_magic, pl_pet = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I'm wondering what's wrong with the code....

Comment: Please edit your question to use proper code formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ValueError: too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053551/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argv array contains not only command-line arguments but also name of the running script so

```
argv[0] = "ex13b.py"
```

Also, by writing

```
pl_magic, pl_pet = argv
```

you are expecting argv to contain only 2 values while in command-line arguments you are giving 3 arguments. That makes argv contain a total of 4 values because the first value is always script name.

Your code should look something like this:

```
script_name, pl_magic, pl_pet, third_argument = argv
```

That being said, you shouldn't just try to unpack things blindly but also add some checks for example:

```
args_count = len(argv) - 1
if args_count < 3:
    #do something if not enough arguments provided
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
pl_magic, pl_pet = argv
```

And enter the parameters (remember, you should take the filename into account in `sys.argv`):

```
ex13b.py 1 2 3
```

You actually run the following line:

```
pl_magic, pl_pet = ['ex13b.py', '1', '2', '3']
```

When unpacking values into variables, you need the same number of variables and values. This is why your code won't work.

You can use:

```
_, par1, par2, par3 = sys.argv
```

---

In Python 3 you can also use:

```
_, par1, *par2 = sys.argv
```

Which will result in:

```
_ = 'ex13b.py'
par1 = '1'
par2 = ['2', '3']
```