# WTF Form SelectField ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I need help with this error, I have a series of SelectFields with multiple choices declared in the class like this one:

```
 TIP_FINANZIAMENTO = SelectField('TIP_FINANZIAMENTO' choices=[('',''),('01', '01 -Mortage with amortization/repayment plan'),('02'......... 
and goes on for a while, it's pretty long.
```

There are more than one like this.
I have tried to remove all choices because I thought maybe I put too many but it returns the same error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

These fields are then passed to a QuickForm in the front end page.
Any Idea why this is happening?

> RETURNS THE FOLLOWING ERROR
>       File "/home/itad/DICP_evo_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py",
>   line 454, in iter_choices

```
        super(SelectField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)

        self.coerce = coerce

        self.choices = copy(choices)



    def iter_choices(self):

        for value, label in self.choices:

            yield (value, label, self.coerce(value) == self.data)



    def process_data(self, value):

        try:

            self.data = self.coerce(value)
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Might be the version of Flask? I have the following Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.4.0
Flask-Moment==0.7.0
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2

Comment: on the official website Version 2.2 has this : Fix a compatibility issue with SQLAlchemy 2.1 that caused QuerySelectField to fail with ValueError: too many values to unpack. (#391)

Comment: Check this out please https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053615/11230028 it may help you+

Comment: but this is only python issue, I'm using Flask WTF, the error seems coming from there, SelectField from WTF